# Allow Remote Shell Disabled by GPO

Tags: powershell, remote-access, gpo

I'm unable to query remote servers due to remote shell being disabled. When I run this command `Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\AllowRemoteShellAccess;` it shows value is `"false"` and source is GPO. However, I am unable to see which GPO sets it, the setting is not being set in RSOP nor `gpresult /v`. Furthermore, the setting itself is "not configured" when checking gpedit.msc and I can change the value anytime. I just want to determine what GPO is setting it. I am not a domain admin.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it will always be "Set by GPO", because GPO controls the feature. Simply, there are two "versions" of GPO, your "Local GPO" which on your machine determine what you can and can't do (both on and off network), and your Domain GPO (which RSOP generates). The Domain GPO will always trump your Local GPO, (which is why you need RSOP). But in cases where the Domain GPO is set to `Not Configured` *your computer* will use whatever the **Local GPO** setting is.

If your Domain GPO is set to `Not Configured`, and if you haven't changed Local GPO setting (because you aren't an Administrator), then you use what the Default setting in Windows is. In this case it depends on the version of Windows:

From [about_Remote_Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-7.1#how-to-configure-your-computer-for-remoting):

> Windows Server 2012 and newer releases of Windows Server are enabled
> for PowerShell remoting by default. If the settings are changed, you
> can restore the default settings by running the `Enable-PSRemoting`
> cmdlet.
>
> On all other supported versions of Windows, you need to run the
> `Enable-PSRemoting` cmdlet to enable PowerShell remoting.

Essentially, the default setting for `PSRemoting` is if you are running:

```
Windows Server == Enabled
Windows 10     == Disabled
```

Since Remote Shell is controlled by GPO, (in your case your Local GPO), you have to set it to `Enabled`. But to make changes to your Local GPO, you have to be an Administrator on your local computer, and hence why you need to run `Enable-PSRemoting` from an elevated prompt.

Comment: thanks, so I suppose there is no Domain GPO setting it. The confusion lies with that it was always enabled for several years now. Then suddenly I am seeing servers with this setting as disabled since just 2 weeks ago. You also mentioned it will be enabled by default for Windows Server, so why now is it disabled by GPO, even a local GPO at that?

Comment: There are other factors that could cause it to be disabled/not working. For ex. it could be firewall related, or the service is not started/set to Autostart, I would go through the troubleshooting to better identify what the root issue may be: [about_remote_troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_troubleshooting?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: ok I'll check further again. Should not be firewall since I can enable it in gpredit.msc and remote shell will work again, there's no service to speak of as well (I believe) since just changing the single setting fixes the issue.